# Uniqueness of the solution for a set of equations (uniqueness of eigenvectors given their eigenvalues)

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance

Given a set of equations with unknowns matrixes X and Y expressed as: 
$$XBX^{T} +YCY^{T} =A$$
where

- A is symmetric and positive definite (i.e. in my particular case it is a covariance matrix),
- C and B are diagonal and positive definite (in my particular case they are the matrixes of eigenvalues of A where the first k eigenvalues are stored on the diagonal of B and the remaining are on the diagonal of C),
- and the unknowns are X and Y (in my case I can put X and Y equal to the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues in B and C respectively),

**the question 1 is: is the solution for X and Y unique subject to the added constraints that $1^{T}X=1$ and $1^{T}Y=1$?**

This question may be rephrased as: provided that we are working with normalized eigenvectors, is it true that the equation above is solved only putting X and Y equal to the normalized eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues in B and C? That is equivalent to saying: are normalized eigenvectors unique for A? **Assume A is a matrix whose eigenvalues are all distinct (i.e. all the eigenvalues have multiplicity 1)**.

The question 2 is **I have read somewhere that it is rare to find estimated covariance matrixes in real-life applications (for example we have a sample of data for random variables and estimate their variance covariance matrix) where some eigenvalues have multiplicity which is not 1. Can you confirm?**

I add this [link](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/showing-that-the-normalized-eigenvector-for-a-distinct-eigenvalue-is-unique.636178/) because it is helpful to the subject of uniqueness of eigenvectors for each eigenvalue with multiplicity 1.

Comment: @loupblanc help if you can, many thanks in advance

Comment: I assume that the considered  matrices are real. You say that $B=diag(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_k,?,?),C=diag(\lambda_{k+1},\cdots,\lambda_n,?,?)$ where $spectrum(A)=(\lambda_i)_i$ is composed with $n$ positive distinct eigenvalues. But what are the $?,?$ (the other elements of the diagonals); are they arbitrary $>0$ reals ?

Comment: @loupblanc I am so sorry for the misspelling of the problem, I just changed the expression fixing the transpose.. so sorry.. you are right.. god bless me and my lack of focus! Too many hours spent on this!! :-) So sorry thanks a lot

Comment: I don't understand one word of your problem. Give the dimensions of $X,A,B,C$. Give explicitly $B,C$. Are the considered equations $XBX^T+Y^CY^T=A, 1^TX=1^T,1^TY=1^T$ ? You ask if a solution of this system, using eigenvectors (of $A$ ?), is unique. What solution do you think?

Comment: @loupblanc yes I am saying the following: given the set of equations above, they are clearly solved by putting X=normalized eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues on B and Y=normalized eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues on C. Are there any other possible solutions?